# JVM memory initializazion error after windows update

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat, java, heapspace

We have three Windows Server 2003 with 2 GB RAM.

- **Server1**
              tomcat 5.5.25
              jvm version SUN 1.6.0_11-b03
- **Server2**
              tomcat 5.5.25
              jvm version SUN 1.6.0_14-b08
- **Server3**
              tomcat 6.0.18
              jvm version SUN 1.6.0_14-b08

For the three servers JVM parameters are:

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Programmi\Apache Group\apache-tomcat-5.5.25
 -Dcatalina.home=C:\Programmi\Apache Group\apache-tomcat-5.5.25
 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Programmi\Apache Group\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\common\endorsed
 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Programmi\Apache Group\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\temp vfprintf
 -Xms512m
 -Xmx1024m
```

For some months everithing worked fine.
Last friday we installed some windows updates.
After the reboot tomcat doesnt start with error:

```
            Error occurred during initialization of VM
            Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

We reduced the parameter -Xmx1024m to -Xmx768m and now tomcat starts.
But we need greater max heap size
What happened to our servers ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to include "windows" and/or "windows-server-2003" in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem.
I uninstalled windows update KB956572. 
After the first reboot tomcat started normally with -Xmx1024m.
Then I installed again windows update KB956572. 
New reboot: tomcat startup failed with the previous error

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after KB956572 uninstall java can allocate more memory then with this update but less before installation.

I think that reason of problem is described in Microsoft article: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956572/en